# JTree of object type displays some properties of the object but returns the whole object when selected

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a program that adds questions to a jtree. Each question on the Jtree is of type Question which has 3 properties; name, id and questionText. I want my Jtree to display only the question name but when the node is selected, it should show the questionText in a textbox.

The problem is the Jtree displays the question's name as I want it to but, when I select a node of the tree I get a ClassCastException. This is because of the getUserObject() in my treeSelectionListener method. It gets a String returned by getUserObject() and tries to cast it to a Question class. How do I get the selected String's Question class properties like questionText or id without getUserObject() or is there another way to represent this tree?

Here is my code:

```
public class Question 
{
 public String name;
 public String id;
 public String qText;  
 public Question(String name,String id, String text) 
 {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.qText = text;
 }

 public String getQuestion()
 { return qText; }

 public String getName()
 { return name;}

 public String getId()
 { return id;}

 public void setQuestionText(String text)
 { qText= text; }

 public void setId(String uid)
 { id = uid;}

 @Override
 public String toString() 
 { return   name; }
}
```

Parts of the code to create the tree:

```
public Question rootQ = new Question("Questions", UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "What is your name?");
public DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(rootQ.toString());
public JTree tree = new JTree(rootNode);

initialise(){
 //....other code to initilise
 panel.add(new JScrollPane(tree));
 tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
 tree.setShowsRootHandles(true);
 tree.addTreeSelectionListener(treeMenuClicked);
 tree.setRootVisible(true);
 tree.setVisible(true);
 panel.add(addChild());
}

public TreeSelectionListener treeMenuClicked = new TreeSelectionListener() 
{

public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) 
{
    TreePath currentSelection = tree.getSelectionPath();
    if(currentSelection != null){
     DefaultMutableTreeNode currentNode =  (DefaultMutableTreeNode)currentSelection.getLastPathComponent();
     Object nodeInfo = currentNode.getUserObject();
     Question questionText = (Question)nodeInfo;
     txtQuestion.setText(questionText.getQuestion()); 
    }
}};

public JButton addChild()
{
    JButton btnAddChild = new JButton("Add Child");
    btnAddChild.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {   String userQuestion = txtQuestion.getText();
            TreePath currentSelection = tree.getSelectionPath();
            if (currentSelection != null) {
                Question createdQuestion = new Question(userQuestion,UUID.randomUUID().toString(),userQuestion);
                DefaultMutableTreeNode currentNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) currentSelection.getLastPathComponent();
                DefaultTreeModel model = ((DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel());
                DefaultMutableTreeNode newNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(createdQuestion.toString());
                currentNode.add(newNode);
                model.nodeStructureChanged(currentNode);
            }
        }});
    btnAddChild.setBounds(609, 374, 117, 47);
    return btnAddChild;
}
```

Comment: You seem to pass string (`rootQ.toString()`) as an argument for `DefaultMutableTreeNode`. Please use just `rootQ` as constructor argument because you need to "get" qText from the same.

Comment: @Ajay I have tried this without the toString and have found that it returns the whole object properties on the tree. So a node on my tree will have name, id, and question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Ajay hinted with his comment, instead of

```java
DefaultMutableTreeNode newNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(createdQuestion.toString());
```

simply do

```java
DefaultMutableTreeNode newNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(createdQuestion);
```

You are the one currently setting your user objects to Strings, not the API.

Also, you can get the selected node through `tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent()` instead of always getting selection path and then calling `TreePath.getLastPathComponent()`.

```java
public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) 
{
    DefaultMutableTreeNode currentNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
    if(currentNode != null){         
        Object nodeInfo = currentNode.getUserObject();
        Question questionText = (Question)nodeInfo;
        txtQuestion.setText(questionText.getQuestion()); 
    }
}};
```

Comment: works fine now it turns out I had a toString also when I was adding children to a node